# Spring Boot MongoDB Repository using 127.0.0.1 instead of specified DB

Tags: java, spring, mongodb

I am using Spring Boot with MongoDB repositories to manage my data. I have specified in the src/main/resources/application.properties file:

```
spring.data.mongodb.uri=mongodb://fedoradb:27017
```

However, I am still getting timeouts when trying to do an insert on the repositories:

```
Caused by: com.mongodb.MongoTimeoutException: Timed out after 10000 ms while waiting for a server that matches AnyServerSelector{}. Client view of cluster state is {type=Unknown, servers=[{address=127.0.0.1:27017, type=Unknown, state=Connecting, exception={com.mongodb.MongoException$Network: Exception opening the socket}, caused by {java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused: connect}}]
at com.mongodb.BaseCluster.getServer(BaseCluster.java:82)
at com.mongodb.DBTCPConnector.getServer(DBTCPConnector.java:656)
at com.mongodb.DBTCPConnector.access$500(DBTCPConnector.java:40)
at com.mongodb.DBTCPConnector$MyPort.getConnection(DBTCPConnector.java:505)
at com.mongodb.DBTCPConnector$MyPort.get(DBTCPConnector.java:448)
at com.mongodb.DBTCPConnector.getPrimaryPort(DBTCPConnector.java:407)
at com.mongodb.DBCollectionImpl.update(DBCollectionImpl.java:265)
at com.mongodb.DBCollection.update(DBCollection.java:214)
at com.mongodb.DBCollection.save(DBCollection.java:1058)
at com.mongodb.DBCollection.save(DBCollection.java:1014)
at org.springframework.data.mongodb.core.MongoTemplate$10.doInCollection(MongoTemplate.java:954)
at org.springframework.data.mongodb.core.MongoTemplate.execute(MongoTemplate.java:410)
... 23 more
```

My MongoConfig looks like this:

```
@Configuration
@EnableMongoRepositories(basePackages = {"com.SpringTest.repository"})
@ComponentScan("com.SpringTest.repository")
public class MongoConfig extends AbstractMongoConfiguration {

@Bean
public MongoDbFactory mongoDbFactory() throws Exception {
    return new SimpleMongoDbFactory(new MongoClient(), getDatabaseName());
}

@Override
protected String getDatabaseName() {
    return "sprtest";
}

protected String getDatabaseHost() {
    return "fedoradb";
}

@Bean
@Override
public Mongo mongo() throws Exception {
    MongoClient client = new MongoClient(getDatabaseHost());
    client.setWriteConcern(WriteConcern.SAFE);
    return client;
}

@Bean
public CustomConversions customConversions() {
    List<Converter<?, ?>> converters = Lists.newArrayList();
    converters.add(new OAuth2AuthenticationConverter());
    return new CustomConversions(converters);
}

@Bean
public MappingMongoConverter mongoConverter() throws Exception {
    MongoMappingContext mappingContext = new MongoMappingContext();
    DbRefResolver dbRefResolver = new DefaultDbRefResolver(mongoDbFactory());
    MappingMongoConverter mongoConverter = new MappingMongoConverter(dbRefResolver, mappingContext);
    mongoConverter.setCustomConversions(customConversions());
    return mongoConverter;
}

@Bean(name = "mongoTemplate")
public MongoTemplate mongoTemplate() throws Exception {
    return new MongoTemplate(mongoDbFactory(), mongoConverter());

}
}
```

The exception is occurring in my main class when doing the CommandLineRunner:

```
@SpringBootApplication
@SpringApplicationConfiguration(classes = BootApplication.class)
@ComponentScan(basePackages = {"com.SpringTest", "com.SpringTest.repository"})
public class BootApplication {

@Bean
CommandLineRunner init(final UserRepository userRepository) {
    return new CommandLineRunner() {
        @Override
        public void run(String... args) throws Exception {
            System.out.println("Inserting User into User Repository");
            User user = new User.Builder()
                    .id("id-1")
                    .primaryEmail("test@test.com")
                    .password("test")
                    .firstName("testfirst")
                    .lastName("testnlast")
                    .roles(Lists.newArrayList(Role.ROLE_USER))
                    .build();
            userRepository.save(user);
        }
    };
}    }

public static void main(String[] args) {
    System.out.println("Starting up");
    SpringApplication.run(BootApplication.class, args);
}
```

}

Is the application.properties file not responsible for setting the database location in this case?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found the problem! I want using my mongo client, I was creating a new, default client.

```
@Bean
public MongoDbFactory mongoDbFactory() throws Exception {
return new SimpleMongoDbFactory(new MongoClient(), getDatabaseName());
}
```

changed to

```
@Bean
public MongoDbFactory mongoDbFactory() throws Exception {
return new SimpleMongoDbFactory(mongo(), getDatabaseName());
}
```

Comment: Congrats! However, since this was a mere slip than an actual problem, I suggest closing the question yourself, saving some work for the community. ;)